# PHP DOTNET() not able to load from "System" assembly

Tags: php, .net, assemblies

Trying to use the Microsoft's .NET classes from **System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates** located in **System** assembly raises the following error:

```
$certificate2 = new DOTNET('System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089', 'System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2');
```

> com_exception: Failed to instantiate .Net object [Unwrapped, QI for IDispatch] [0x80004002]  No such interface supported
>    in ...\test.php on line 2

Whereas the following calls do work and return DOTCOM instances.

```
$certificate = new DOTNET('mscorlib', 'System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate');
$form = new DOTNET('System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089', 'System.Windows.Forms.Form');
```

Is there something special to **System.dll** or its classes contained in **System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates**?

Why could this file or classes not be usable?

### digging deeper

The Exception origins to a failed method call in [php_dotnet extension source code](http://www.sourcecodebrowser.com/php5/5.3.3/com__dotnet_8c_source.html), line 250. But this is too low level for me. The call is:

```
hr = IUnknown_QueryInterface(V_UNKNOWN(&unwrapped), &IID_IDispatch, &V_DISPATCH(&obj->v));
```

### side notes

- PHP version is 5.5.5
- this happens on a Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 box
- the assembly seems to accessed correctly, but classes can not be found
- selected .NET Framework Version is 2.0.0.0 (<=3.5), because PHP DOTNET does not work with Version >= 4
- Cryptography classes from mscorlib do not suffice, because of limited functionality

Answer (score 0):

Try this.It's working for me

```
<?php
  $stack = new DOTNET("mscorlib", "System.Collections.Stack");
  $stack->Push(".Net");
  $stack->Push("Hello ");
  echo $stack->Pop() . $stack->Pop();
 ?>
```

The link for the doc, [Click here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dotnet.php)

Comment: Using classes from "mscorlib" works. I already tried this with class "System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate" which works as well as "System.Collections.Stack" does. But this does not solve the problem.

Comment: `mscorlib` is strange because it works with this **wrong** use of `DOTNET()`.